# Gerrit can't display verified and code-review label at same time

Tags: gerrit

I'm using Gerrit 2.16.2. I configured the Gerrit on gui. I added "Label Verified" and "Label Code-Review" permissions with group Administrators in Reference: refs/head/* by administrator user.

But neither of "Verified" button nor "Code Review" button show.
I remove "Label Verified" permission, the "Code Review" button can show,
and I remove "Lavel Code-Review" permission, the "Verified" button can show.

What's wrong of my configuration?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your configuration. The button will only show the next required level. Try clicking on the Reply button and in there you will see both options for voting.

Comment: +1 - To elaborate a bit more on that; those action buttons are defined as "quick approval" buttons. Those will, by design, only show up if it's the single last label vote to approve the change. See also [Issue 9594](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=9594), [Issue 10529 comment 4](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=10529#c4).